# Job Template in Ansible Tower using API Endpoint

Tags: node.js, ansible, ansible-tower

How to create a job template in ansible tower using Api Endpoint in nodejs script.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. What did you try and which problem are you facing exactly ?

Comment: @Zeitounator Thanks... Actually I am not getting how to create a nodejs for creating job template in ansible tower.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I am not familiar with node.js.  But as far as the Ansible part goes, navigate your browser to `https://my-ansible-tower/api/v2/job_templates`.  At the bottom of the page, you will see the options you can set:

```
{
    "name": "",
    "description": "",
    "job_type": "run",
    "inventory": null,
    "project": null,
    "playbook": "",
    "forks": 0,
    "limit": "",
    "verbosity": 0,
    "extra_vars": "",
    "job_tags": "",
    "force_handlers": false,
    "skip_tags": "",
    "start_at_task": "",
    "timeout": 0,
    "use_fact_cache": false,
    "host_config_key": "",
    "ask_diff_mode_on_launch": false,
    "ask_variables_on_launch": false,
    "ask_limit_on_launch": false,
    "ask_tags_on_launch": false,
    "ask_skip_tags_on_launch": false,
    "ask_job_type_on_launch": false,
    "ask_verbosity_on_launch": false,
    "ask_inventory_on_launch": false,
    "ask_credential_on_launch": false,
    "survey_enabled": false,
    "become_enabled": false,
    "diff_mode": false,
    "allow_simultaneous": false,
    "custom_virtualenv": null,
    "job_slice_count": 1,
    "credential": null,
    "vault_credential": null
}
```

Set those in your node.js script and pust to that URL.  That should work.

Good luck!